# Obtaining element with addEventListener and bound functions

Tags: javascript

When using **bound functions** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in conjunction with **addEventListener** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler) what is the best method of obtaining the element that the event is attached to?

Below is an example of a potential scenario. Each LI has an click event listener than triggers a method in the module. To avoid unnecessary anonymous functions/this/that (https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/#what-problem-are-we-actually-looking-to-solve), the module scope is passed to the event handler. In a typical event handler `this` would be the element that has the event attached; however, `this` would refer to the module in this situation. `e.target` refers to the element clicked on, not necessarily the element with the event. Is there a better method than passing the element with the event as the code below does?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
function Module() {
    this.element = document.querySelectorAll("li");

  for(var i=0; i<this.element.length; i++) {
    this.element[i].addEventListener("click", this.link.bind(this, this.element[i]));
  }
}

Module.prototype.link = function(el, e) {
  //How to get the current element with the associated listener? Normally "this" would be the element.
  //e.target is the A tag, not the LI tag with the attached event listener
  //Passing the el variable seems less than optimal. Better solution?
};

var instance = new Module();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1sj68d4n/

Adding the event listener to the A tag instead of the Li may solve the issue in this niche circumstance. However, in many cases an listener may be attached to an element with many children.

Comment: This is an attempt to recreate jQuery? There are several issues with the approach you are taking that are solved by jQuery. Perhaps you should just use that library, or at least consult its design. As it stands, I would suggest refactoring more than hacking this together.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with passing it in as a parameter.  I've seen it done before in some very popular libraries.  I believe Backbone's implementation of the .on method will pass in the event context as one of the parameters.

jQuery binds the context of the 'this' keyword to the element which was the context of the event.  In your case, if you did that you would loose access to any reference back to the module instance though.

jQuery also creates a custom event object which holds references to all kinds of extra potentially useful objects like relatedTarget and delegateTarget.  You may consider an approach like that.

**Memory Leak:**
One more practical problem with this implementation is that you won't be able to unbind this handler since there is no reference stored to it.  This will create a memory leak as the handler will maintain an internal reference to the event context causing it to remain in memory.  The garbage collector will see the reference and won't clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solid solution. The original element the event handler is attached to is passed in the event element as `e.currentTarget`.